Why does the variance tend to $\sigma^2/n$?
Let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ be the income of $n$ individuals with $E(Y_i) = \mu$ and $\text{Var}(Y_i) = \sigma^2$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. These $n$ individuals form $m$ groups, each of size $k$. It is known that individuals within the same group are correlated, but two individuals in different groups are always independent. Assume that when individuals are correlated, the correlation coefficient is the same for all pairs.
Consider the random variable $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ The limiting variance of $\bar{Y}$ when $m$ is large but $k$ is finite is
Options:

(A) $ 0$
(B) $\frac{1}{k}$
(C) $1$
(D) $\frac{\sigma^2}{k}$

Based on some calculations, I calculated $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{Y}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}(1+(k-1)r)$ ($r$ is the correlation coefficient). Based on this as, $n \rightarrow \infty$ the variance term must tend to zero, but when I consult chatGPT it says that the variance is non-zero because of the correlations between the members of a group. Is this true and if so why?

Within each group of $k$ people, you presumably find the variance of the mean is $\frac{\sigma^2}{k}(1+(k-1)r)$,
corresponding to the variance of the overall mean over $km=n$ people being $\frac{\sigma^2}{km}(1+(k-1)r)$,
which with $k$ fixed tends $\to 0$ as $m$ increases.  Why do you think ChatGPT knows anything?

By conceiving of $\bar Y$ in terms of the mean of the group averages, and recognizing the group averages have a finite variance, you put yourself back into the elementary iid situation and can apply any law of large numbers or even the Central Limit Theory without any hesitation.

Both comments make sense to me and now I'm confused.
